# Program to remove preceding whitespace

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I am working on a program that should remove preceding spaces and tabs from each line of text in a given file (case b). I read the file from stdin, which I got working fine. However I am getting a nasty seg fault that I can't figure out. It happens when I call strcat() in case b. Basically what I was trying to do in case b is iterate through each line (80 characters) in the text file, remove any preceding tabs or spaces from the line, then put these lines back into finalText. Can anyone see where am I going wrong? Or if there might be a simpler approach?

Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int count = 1;

    char *text = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
    char *finalText =  malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
    char buff[80];

    while(fgets(buff, 80, stdin) != NULL){
        strcat(text, buff);

    }


    while ((x = getopt(argc, argv, "bic:")) != -1){
        switch (x){
            case 'b':
                for(; text[i] != EOF; i += 80){

                    char buff2[80];
                    char *buff3;
                    j = i;
                    y = 0;
                    while(j != (80 * count)){
                        buff2[y] =  text[j];
                        y++;
                        j++;
                    }
                    buff3 = buff2;
                    while(*buff3 && isspace(*buff3)){
                        ++buff3;
                    }
                    count++;
                    strcat(finalText, buff3);
                }
                printf(finalText);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: very descriptive variable names... :/

Comment: put `*text = '\0';` before while-loop.

Comment: There are no guarantees about the contents of memory returned by `malloc()`. Therefore, the first time you get a chunk of memory back that either contains no NULL bytes or the first NULL byte is sufficiently far into the region that appending your `buff` data will exceed the size of the region, you are guaranteed to be writing outside the bounds of the region of memory you just acquired. You need to initialize the memory that you get from `malloc()`... And, depending on further logic, there may be additional points where you want to re-initialize it...

Comment: Are you sure that text[i] will contain EOF?

Comment: I think this is not a good approach: for(; text[i] != EOF; i += 80){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char buff[80];
    int n;
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin)){
        sscanf(buff, " %n", &n);
        if(n && buff[n-1] == '\n')//only whitespaces line.(nothing first word)
            //putchar('\n');//output a newline.
            fputs(buff, stdout);//output as itself .
        else
            fputs(buff + n, stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This look like a possible solution. Wouldn't this delete every space though, instead of only the preceding spaces on each line?

Comment: @mjones this remove preceding spaces and tabs from each line of text in a given file.

Comment: right but I _only_ want to delete the tabs or spaces before the _first_ word on each line. This is what I'm having trouble with. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @mjones this delete the tabs or spaces before the first word on each line. Is there a line of only whitespace characters?

Comment: @mjones My code does not remove the space between the word. Can you explain in a concrete example the problem of my code?

Comment: I just tried your code, it does indeed work. Much simpler than I thought it could be. Thanks

Comment: I did. could you explain exactly how fputs(buff + n, stdout); works though. Specifically the buff + n part?

Comment: @mjones It will be output from the characters that are not blank.

Comment: You could also consider using `n = strspn(buff, " \t");` which returns the number of tabs and blanks at the start of the line.  You then don't have to test for newlines because it doesn't skip them (I didn't include `'\n'` in the list of characters to be 'spanned' or skipped).

Comment: Get it. I think that you should be written  your own in order to show the different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly before the `'b'` case, there is another problem too. You have allocated 1024 byte for `text`. Each line you read from `stdin` is concatenated at `text` string. If the total characters read from `stdin` exceed 1024 bytes you will receive a segmentation fault.

For your problem at `'b'` case:
Why searching for `EOF`? `EOF` is not a character and your loop will continue to iterating incrementing `i` until you receive a segmentation fault. You just want to iterate until the end of the string which can be retrieved with `strlen()` for example.